# CKEditor Change Config Setting on Focus / Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I need to be able to change the filebrowserUploadUrl of CKEditor when I change some details on the page, as the querystring I pass through is used by the custom upload process I've put in place.

I'm using the JQuery plugin. Here's my code:

```
$('#Content').ckeditor({
    extraPlugins: 'autogrow',
    autoGrow_maxHeight: 400,
    removePlugins: 'resize'
});

$("#Content").ckeditorGet().on("instanceReady", function () {
    this.on("focus", function () {
        // Define browser Url from selected fields
        this.config.filebrowserUploadUrl = filebrowserUploadUrl: '/my-path-to-upload-script/?ID1=' + $("ID1").val() + '&ID2=' + $("#ID2").val();
    });
});
```

This works fine the first time, but if I come out of the dialogue and change the value of #ID1 and #ID2, it keeps the previous values. When I debug, the filebrowserUploadUrl is set correctly, but it doesn't affect the submission values. It seems the config values are cached.

Is there any way to change a config value on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reloading the editor whenever a change occurred; I actually went through the source code for the browser plugin etc, but couldn't get any changes to work (and of course, I really didn't want to change anything for future upgrades).

```
function setFileBrowserUrl() {
    // Remove editor instance
    $("#Content").ckeditorGet().destroy();
    // Recreate editor instance (needed to reset the file browser url)
    createEditor();
}
function createEditor() {
    $('#Content').ckeditor({
        filebrowserUploadUrl: '/my-path-to-upload-script/?ID1=' + $("ID1").val() + '&ID2=' + $("#ID2").val(),
        extraPlugins: 'autogrow',
        autoGrow_maxHeight: 400,
        removePlugins: 'resize'
    });
}
```

Then I call setFileBrowserUrl every time the relevant elements on the page change. Not ideal, but it works for my purposes :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently I don't see any possibility to change this URL on the fly without hacking.

Take a look at http://dev.ckeditor.com/browser/CKEditor/trunk/_source/plugins/filebrowser/plugin.js#L306

This `element.filebrowser.url` property is set once and as you can see few lines above it will be reused again. You can try to somehow find this element and reset this property, but not having deeper understanding of the code of this plugin I don't know how.

Second option would be to change this line #L284 to:

`url = undefined;`

However, I haven't check if this is the correct solution :) Good luck!

BTW. Feel free to fill an issue on http://dev.ckeditor.com.